# Can't figure out how remote share is getting automounted

Tags: network, automount

I have a NAS that stores the music files for iTunes. There is an automounted share on the NAS that iTunes goes thru to retrieve the music files. For the life of me I can't figure out how the automount is defined. I need to change NAS units, and therefore need to change the share mount.

The share is mounted to /Network/media and looks and acts like an automount. (Comes and goes on demand.) The /etc/auto_* files appear pristine, yet...

```
sol:etc sjf$ sudo automount -vc
automount: /net updated
automount: /home updated
automount: /Network/media updated
automount: no unmounts
```

shows  that /Network/media is  being controlled by automount

/etc/auto_master...

```
#
# Automounter master map
#
+auto_master        # Use directory service
/net            -hosts      -nobrowse,hidefromfinder,nosuid
/home           auto_home   -nobrowse,hidefromfinder
/Network/Servers    -fstab
/-          -static
```

and /etc/auto_home...

```
#
# Automounter map for /home
#
+auto_home  # Use directory service
#
# Get /home records synthesized from user records
#
+/usr/libexec/od_user_homes
```

There is no /etc/fstab, but there's an /etc/fstab.hd. It only contains...

```
IGNORE THIS FILE.
This file does nothing, contains no useful data, and might go away in
future releases.  Do not depend on this file or its contents.
```

The mount I want to change is...

```
nas2.controlsoftcorp.com:/media on /Network/media (nfs, nodev, nosuid, automounted, nobrowse)
```

What am I missing?

(currently using 10.8, but need to solve this issue on 10.9 too.)

Answer (score -2):

Well the answer is that it is entered using Directory Utility.